# CORS in .Net 7.0 with React

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, traefik, .net-7.0

I am trying to call an API from the frontend, but I get CORS error. Front and Back are running on the same domain but on different sub domain.

It's working in this situation :

- API works on Postman
- API works on browser (Copy/Pasting the API on browser)
- in dev (`localhost:3000` calling `localhost:7021`)
- in local Docker (`https://localhost:13000` calling `https://localhost:17021`)

CORS error appears when I call the API in React in production behind Docker. I make my API calls via Axios.

Here is my code from back-end :

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);

builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQL")));
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

builder.Services.AddCors(p =>
    p.AddDefaultPolicy(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins(configuration["OriginAllowed"]!).AllowCredentials())
);

...

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .WithOrigins(configuration["OriginAllowed"]!)
                            .AllowCredentials());

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

...
```

Front-end :

Call from my Service.js :

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/user`;

const login = async(userData) => {
    const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/login`, userData, {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"      
    })
    if (response.data) {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data))
    }
    return response.data
}
```

Moreover, from my preflight response header in the access-control-allow-methods only contains GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT but not POST whereas I accept all methods.

I have tested responses to :

- AllowAnyOrigin() and AllowAnyMethod() in UseCors and AddCors
- Change the call order Program.cs functions
- Add proxy to my package.json in my react app. But this is not a dev environmnent.
- Add EnableCors to my Controllers but didn't work either and I don't know if this is the fix I want.
- Not add the Policy as AddDefaultPolicy but AddPolicy and name it and reuse the name into my UseCors().

**What I want**

Calling my back end API with URL `https://mysubdomain-backend.mydomain.com` from my front end website `https://mysubdomain-frontend.mydomain.com` with 200 OK

Comment: enable cors at backend

Comment: It's already the case as you can see in my Program.cs

Comment: have you solved this isse?